# JS/JQuery. How to create a working button?

Tags: jquery

(I am not sure how to title this post).

Consider the following code. 
I have a button to remove some text and to insert a new button. 
The new button is inserted fine, but nothing happens when it is clicked (a simple popoup should appear). Firebug does not help. I suspect I do NOT know something on how to use $(document).ready.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>tre.html</title>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="..../jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetButton() {
    $('ul.eventlist button.reset')
        .unbind('click')
        .bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
alert($(this).parent().html());
alert('mario');
});
}
function removeButton() {
    $('ul.eventlist button.remove')
        .unbind('click')
        .bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
var reset = $('<li><button class="reset" ><span>Reset</span></button> New text</li>'); 
$(this).parent().parent().append(reset);
$(this).parent().remove();
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   removeButton();
   resetButton();
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="eventlist">
<li><button class="remove"><span>Delete</span></button> Some Text
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the document ready function when you call the `resetButton()` function the reset button does not exist. You need to call that function inside the `removeButton()`, after the reset button has been created.

For example:

```
function removeButton() {
    $('ul.eventlist button.remove')
        .unbind('click')
        .bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var reset = $('<li><button class="reset" ><span>Reset</span></button> New text</li>'); 
        $(this).parent().parent().append(reset);
        $(this).parent().remove();
        resetButton();
    });
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/7AAws/2/

Comment: event delegation would be a lot safer....if OP uses repeating rows of these, will be adding more and more click handlers to each button

Answer (score 0):

Hey u r binding function at page loading....
But at that time reset button does not exist.

So call resetButton() inside removeButton()